# Jupyter Notebook magic %alias doesn't work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried the following very known example of %alias in Jupiter Notebook:

```
%alias bracket echo "Input in brackets: <%l>"
bracket hello world
```

This is supposed to output:

```
Input in brackets: <hello world>
```

Instead, I get the following:

```
File "<ipython-input-12-237eb6e9d860>", line 1
alias bracket echo "Input in brackets: <%l>"
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have cleared everything, shutdown the book and even restarted the kernel. So it's not a question of some "garbage" in cache. I have tried a lot of different things with `%alias`. Nothing works. I even get "'xxx' is not defined", where 'xxx' is the name used for alias.

Additional info:

1) If I execute just `bracket` (no argument), I receive an error: "bracket is not defined". I find this quite crazy. I hope you don't and know the reason why this happens.

2) I am using Jupyter Notebook 5.6.0.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to duplicate your issue and putting a `%` in front of the `bracket` calls treats them as the actual alias you are creating.

```
%alias bracket echo "Input in brackets: <%l>"

%bracket hello world
%bracket 'hello world'
%bracket (1)
```

Output:

```
"Input in brackets: <hello world>" 
"Input in brackets: <'hello world'>" 
"Input in brackets: <(1)>"
```

For notebook server 5.7.4, Python 3.7.1, and IPython 7.2.0

Comment: Does this resolve your issue? Or are you still having issues?

Comment: Thanks, but none of these work for me. I always get "Invalid syntax" after the command `bracket`. And If I don't add any argument at all (like 'hello'), I get "bracket is not defined". I have tried all sorts of combinations and tests: the magic `%alias` simply doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Can you restart your kernel then run just `%alias bracket echo "Input in brackets: <%l>"` to define the alias and then in a separate cell run only `%alias`? This will list everything that's currently defined. Also, what are you hosting jupyter on? Windows, Linux, AWS?

Comment: Also, if you just run `%lsmagic` in a cell, do you see `%alias` as an available line magic?

Comment: "kdq0", Yes, of course. Also `%alias??` shows info about the magic like the rest of them. And I have restarted the kernel quite a few times and I have used it in different notebooks, always in a cell of itself.

Comment: Note: It's not the only magic that doesn't work. `%autocall 0|1|2` doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you tell us what version of `IPython` you are running in the notebook? You can find this under *Help > About > Current Kernel Information*.

Comment: *kd0*, it's 6.5.0. But what does this has to do from the moment that `%alias` is in its list of magics and more, that they give the **exact** example that I used as a test and which doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6.8

jupyter version: 4.4.0

Notebook server: 5.7.8

```
%alias bracket echo "Input in brackets: <%l>"
bracket hello world
bracket'hello world'
bracket(1)
```

Output:

```
"Input in brackets: <hello world>"
"Input in brackets: <'hello world'>" 
"Input in brackets: <(1)>"
```

Comment: Thanks, but none of these work for me. I always get "Invalid syntax" after the command `bracket`. And If I don't add any argument at all (like 'hello'), I get "bracket is not defined" !

Comment: update your jupyter notebook server to 5.7.X and try it.

Comment: #Vishal, thanks but it's not a question of version.